# Query latency increases when connections to DB increases without any change in query throughput

Tags: mysql-5.6, java

We are currently using HikariCP to manage our connection pool and our ORM is eclispelink.

We have the following observation: On production, when the max number of DB connections to master database crosses a comfortable threshold then the performance (query latency increases) degrades. And this relation is independent of throughput. We have tried to reproduce this scenario multiple times in our performance testing environment. The observation is as follows: Max DB connections : 420 
Transactional TPS reached (write operations) ~ 600

As soon as, we had added new connections and went to around 680. Latency had kicked in. There was no change in load from application servers. This is strange, since we have not added any more load, just by increasing number of connections, performance starts degrading. This continues till we bring back the number of connections to its comfortable value.

Are we missing something here?

Comment: Sounds like you could benefit from a read through here if you have not: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing